# How can fix the size of view in mac in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am experiencing a new change with Xcode Version 14.1 about view size in macOS, in older version if I gave a frame size or use fixedSize modifier, the view would stay in that size, but with 14.1 I see that view could get expended even if I use frame or fixedSize modifier, which is not what I expect. For example I made an example to show the issue, when I update the size to 200.0, the view/window stay in bigger size, which I expect it shrinks itself to smaller size, so how can I solve the issue?

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var sizeOfWindow: CGFloat = 400.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            
            Text("Hello, world!")
            
            Button("update", action: {
                
                if (sizeOfWindow == 200.0) { sizeOfWindow = 400.0 }
                else { sizeOfWindow = 200.0 }
                
                print(sizeOfWindow)
                
            })
        }
        .frame(width: sizeOfWindow, height: sizeOfWindow)
        .fixedSize()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Credit:

- Credit to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708177?answerId=717217022#717217022

## Approach:

- Use `.windowResizability(.contentSize)`
- Along with `windowResizability` use one of the following:

  - if you want set size based on the content size use `fixedSize()`
  - If you want to hardcode the frame then directly set `.frame(width:height:)`

## Code

```
@main
struct DemoApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200) //or use fixed size and rely on content
        }
        .windowResizability(.contentSize)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be happy to accept this good answer for my question, but my minimum deployment is 12.3 macOS and `.windowResizability(.contentSize)` is just available for macOS 13.0 or newer, should I downgrade my Xcode version for solving this issue? But also that is not possible because I already have mac 13.0 and mac 13.0 needs Xcode +14.0, so what should I do?!

Comment: I am not sure, I was trying to use `@available` / `#available` the problem I was stuck was Scene doesn't support if statements. I am sure there is a way. Try raising it with Apple TSI (DTS team).

Comment: Also try replying to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708177?answerId=717217022#717217022

Comment: @ioscoder, I know this is a bit late, but you can use the answer here to make windowResizability conditional on macOS version: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/719389